# Deleting iTunes folder after Catalina update

Tags: itunes, catalina

Is it okay to delete the iTunes folder (~/Music/iTunes/) after updating to macOS Catalina? There is also a Music folder inside the Music folder which has the 'Music Library' file in it. I am assuming this corresponds to the new Apple Music app. The iTunes Media folder also has a "Apple Music" folder inside it. Thus, I am totally confused if the files are required or not for the proper functioning of the new Apple Music app. Can anyone tell if it is safe to delete this iTunes folder such that the new Apple Music and Apple TV apps remain unaffected?

Comment: I also have this question. My old folder is massive.